# Xcode Error While Running Build

Tags: xcode, parsing, build

I'm getting this error while running a build, What can be the reason of the problem?

[image]

Comment: You should mention things that you have tried to do to fix the problem. Also it might be useful to mention what libraries you are using since a brief look at the picture suggests that some library is not being linked properly.

Comment: It is looking already linked on xcode

Answer (score 1):

GameKit framework is not linked because it does not provide all required architecture.
Why are you trying to link a system framework from /Users/default/Downloads/... instead of regular GameKit.framework from official SDK ?

Comment: How can i download the official gamekit.framework? I couldn't find any download link

Comment: You should have it, in your project setting, for your target, in Linked frameworks and Libraries, click + button and add GameKit

Comment: Check your target's build settings for another GameKit